# Timeout in spring transaction anootation for REPEATABLE_READ

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

If I apply a timeout on `@Transactional`, will it unlock the row after timeout or will throw the exception?

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.REPEATABLE_READ, timeout=100)
public ExternalServerListenerInfo getTokenForLiveScoutListener() {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I found the answer below:

> Timeout specifies the maximum time allowed for a transaction to run. This may be required since transactions that run for a very long time may unnecessarily hold locks for a long time. When a transaction reaches the timeout period, it is rolled back. Timeout needs to be specified only on propagation settings that start a new transaction (from http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-transaction-attributes.jsp)

So, from the details, it appears that it will rollback the transaction and release the lock from the database.